# How to convert a value into static value in oracle/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

say i have

```
select * from table1
join table2
on table1.name = table2.name
where table1.date = table2.date
```

if in this case table2.date = '13-NOV-13 12.00.00.000000 AM'
i want to convert table2.date in to static value
something like `where table1.date = somefunction(table2.date)`
so it'll be

```
where table1.date = '13-NOV-13 12.00.00.000000 AM'
```

how do you do this in oracle 11g.
Thanks!

Comment: Is `table1.date` a varchar2 and `table2.date` is a timestamp?  What's the reason for the type conversion?

Comment: table1.date is a timestamp also.i want table1.date to use static value from table2.date for a given search.

Answer (score 0):

You can format a date as a string using built-in function [to_date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm), let's say:

```
where table1.date = to_date(table2.date, 'dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mi:ss')
```